# How to uninstall a package using python-apt and also remove dependencies?

Tags: python, apt, deb

I want to remove a package using [python-apt](https://apt-team.pages.debian.net/python-apt/library/apt.cache.html#apt.cache.ProblemResolver.remove) and also remove all dependendencies.
Basically the equivalent to

```bash
apt purge PACKAGE
apt autoremove
```

However I can’t figure out the dependency part.
I guess this has to be done using the `ProblemResolver` class?

Here is my code, that removes a package but does not uninstall dependencies:

```py
import apt

cache = apt.Cache()
resolver = apt.cache.ProblemResolver(cache)
pkg = cache['PACKAGE_NAME']

if pkg.is_installed:
    pkg.mark_delete(True, purge=True)
    
    # does nothing
    resolver.remove(pkg)
    resolver.resolve()
else:
    raise InvalidUsage(package + " is not installed", status_code=400)

try:
    result = cache.commit(allow_unauthenticated=True)
    cache.update()
    cache.open()
except Exception as arg:
    raise Exception(
        "Sorry, purging package failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg)))
```

Comment: The question is about Debian packages using the python-apt API, not python packages

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a workaround and will share it here.
If anybody could provide a proper solution, I will be very interested :-)

I tried iterating over the dependencies and purging those manually. But this will only remove the direct dependencies. Doing so recursively will remove more packages but far less then what `apt autoremove` would.

## Workaround: ask `apt-get` shell command to provide a list

So what I did is start a [shell command](https://askubuntu.com/a/652531/873460) that will provide a list of orphaned packages and iterate over this:

```py
import apt
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

cache = apt.Cache()
pkg = cache['PACKAGE_NAME']

if pkg.is_installed:
    pkg.mark_delete(purge=True)
else:
    raise InvalidUsage(package + " is not installed", status_code=400)
try:
    result = cache.commit()
    cache.update()
    cache.open()
except Exception as arg:
    raise Exception(
        "Sorry, purging package failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg)))

dependencies = []

# Now, after package was removed, apt will list autoremovable packages
# https://askubuntu.com/a/652531/873460
ps = Popen("apt-get --dry-run autoremove | grep -Po '^Remv \K[^ ]+'", shell=True, stdout=PIPE)
output = ps.stdout.read()
ps.stdout.close()
ps.wait()
dependencies = output.splitlines()

# mark for removal
for pkg in dependencies:
    cache[pkg.decode()].mark_delete(purge=True)

try:
    cache.commit()
    cache.update()
    cache.open()
except Exception as arg:
    raise Exception(
        "Sorry, purging package failed [{err}]".format(err=str(arg)))
```